# Listening to page changes from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm building a Chrome extension to track the time user spent on let's say http://example.com. So basically when the user changes to another tab with different URL it stops the timer, and when she comes back to the first tab or when she changes her current tab's URL to http://example.com the timer restarts.

Question is: **how do I do that with the least permissions possible**?

Here are my ideas:

**1. Using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` and `chrome.tabs.onActivated`**
Every time a tab gets updates or the user changes tab, I check if the url matches http://example.com. If yes then I save `new Date()` in a variable, and whenever the URL changes again, I substract that variable from the new `new Date()`.

**2. Content Scripts?**
I insert a content script only on http://example.com which sends a message to background.js with the current `new Date()`. I don't even believe in this idea, but maybe this script can somehow detect when the tab is not active anymore? And send another message to background.js.

**3. Using [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation)**
This would be my best bet. I have the following code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
function onWebNav(details) {
    console.log(details)
}
var filter = {
    url: [{
        hostSuffix: 'example.com'
    }]
};

chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
```

No output in the extension's console when I navigate to http://example.com.

**4. Using [`declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent)**
If I understood that correctly, there are only a few actions possible (like: `actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]` to show the page action). Can I define my own actions with my own code?

Can anybody tell me which is the way to go?

Comment: I think #1 is the obvious winner so why don't you like it?

Comment: I need the `tab` permission to access `tab.url`. I'm just thinking if there's a way to do this only using the `activeTab` permission.

Comment: As you can read in the first line of [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) documentation the user should click something in your extension.

Comment: Yeah I'll go with that then.